# Data Cleanup with R: Getting rid of extra fullstops

Tags: r

I am cleaning the data using R.

Below is my data format
Input

```
1) 100      |  101.25  | 102.25. | .   | .. | 201.5. |
2) 200.05.  |  200.56. | 205     | ..  | .  | 3000   |
3) 300.98   |  300.26. | 2001.56.| ... | 0.2| 5.65.  |
```

expected output:

```
1) 100   | 101.25   | 102.25  |NA | NA |201.5
2) 200.05|200.26    | 205     |NA | NA |3000
3) 300.98|300.26    |2001.26  |NA |0.2 |5.65
```

there are extra full stops at in the table, which I am trying to get cleaned, but to retain decimal numbers in its format

I tried replace all in R, which clears all the full stops, and decimal numbers are distorted.

Comment: Do you need the numbering at the start?

Comment: Is the trailing full stop the only type of problem, or are there other cases as well?

Comment: any format will be helpful, Thanks - Praveen

Comment: Please accept / upvote any (if not all) of your seven other questions!

Comment: So you have a Problem with data or with console output? Dput of a Sample would help.

Comment: @PraveenMKulkarni You can accept answer to a question by clicking on `tick` symbol that is shown in left of answer box. Its always better to accept answer so that it will be helpful for future user. Perhaps you can accept answer to all your previous questions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `look-ahead` to replace dot(`.`) which are not before `space` or `|` as:

x <- '1) 100      |  101.25  | 102.25. | .   | .. | 201.5. |
  2) 200.05.  |  200.56. | 205     | ..  | .  | 3000   |
3) 300.98   |  300.26. | 2001.56.| ... | 0.2| 5.65.  |'

```
y <- gsub("([.]+)(?=[[:blank:]|])","",x,perl = TRUE)

cat(y)
# 1) 100      |  101.25  | 102.25 |    |  | 201.5 |
# 2) 200.05  |  200.56 | 205     |   |   | 3000   |
# 3) 300.98   |  300.26 | 2001.56|  | 0.2| 5.65  |
```

**Regex explanation:**

`([.]+)`           -  Group any number of `.` before look-ahead

`(?=[[:blank:]|])` -  Look-ahead before `:blank:` or `|`

**Data:**

```
x <- '1) 100      |  101.25  | 102.25. | .   | .. | 201.5. |
  2) 200.05.  |  200.56. | 205     | ..  | .  | 3000   |
3) 300.98   |  300.26. | 2001.56.| ... | 0.2| 5.65.  |'
```

Answer (score 3):

If the trailing full stop is really the only manifestation of the problem, then you may try just removing it with `sub`:

```
x <- c("101.25", "200.56.", "300.26")
x <- sub("\\.$", "", x)
```

Comment: @Jan But seriously, _seven_ abandoned other questions?  Is it really too much trouble to click the mouse?

Comment: Maybe it's a keyboard-only terminal?

Comment: very new to stackoverflow, searching to 'how to close the question' :(